# How do i find the order of a permutation in the group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How can i define the order of a permutation without doing the permutation again and again? Example: say $σ=(1-->2,2-->3,3-->5,4-->1,5-->4)$ in $S_5$.

Comment: Some friendly advice: do not ask a second question when you should ask a *new*@ question (new post). It makes the answers you received seem incomplete. If you have questions about how to find the inverse of a permutation, you need to first search the site to find one of the many duplicate questions on that, or, if you cannot find a duplicate, post it as a new question.

Comment: Im really sorry for the re editing.

Comment: No problem, Manolis. As I said, I was offering some friendly advice.

Comment: Advice is taken.I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the permutation in cycle notation (and expressed as the product of *disjoint* cycles).

For each cycle in the permutation determine its length. (If there is only one cycle of length greater than $1$, then the order of the permutation is the length of that cycle. If all cycles in a permutation are of length one, it is necessarily the identity permutation, and has order $1$.

Calculate the least common multiple of all cycle lengths.

The result is the order of the permutation.

Example: Let $\tau =\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\ 2& 4 & 5 & 1& 3\end{pmatrix}$

Written as the product of *disjoint* cycles gives us $\tau = (1, 2, 4)(3, 5) \in S_5$.

Then the lengths of the cycles, from left to right, are $3, 2$.

$\operatorname{lcm}(3, 2) = 6$.

The order of $\tau$ is equal to $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The order is the least common multiplier of the length of all circles in the
 circle notation of the permutation.

Comment: you mean lcm of the lengths of all the "cycles" in the "disjoint cycle" representation of the permutation.

Comment: Can you o an example pease. Say $S5$ $$σ=(1-->2,2-->3,3,-->5,4-->1,5-->4)$$

Comment: @manolis that has one cycle of length 5, so the order is 5.

Comment: The cycle notation is (12354) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The element that you have listed isn't  permutation because it sends both $4$ and $5$ to $1$. If, however, you had $\sigma = (1235) \in S_5$, then you can find the order by simply multiplying the permutation by itself:
$$\begin{align}
\sigma^1 &= (1235) \\
\sigma^2 &= (13)(25) \\
\sigma^3 &= (1532) \\
\sigma^4 &= (1).
\end{align}
$$
So the order of $\sigma$ is $4$.

This, obviously, only works when the group is relatively small.

---

If you wanted to ask about the order of $\sigma = (12354)$, then just star
$$\begin{align}
\sigma^1 &= (12354) \\
\sigma^2 &= (13425) \\
\sigma^3 &= \dots.
\end{align}
$$

---

In case you are not familiar with the notation, $(1235)$ is the permutation that 
$$\begin{align}
1 &\longrightarrow 2 \\
2 &\longrightarrow 3 \\
3 &\longrightarrow 5 \\
5 &\longrightarrow 1\\
4 &\longrightarrow 4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: sorry i meant 5-->3

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis: It still doesn't work.

Comment: ******5--->4 sorry